# RetryContext is not updated to exhausted=true, on reaching maxAttempts

Tags: spring, spring-retry, retry-logic

Is there a bug in the spring-retry using retryTemplate ? I see that after the maxAttempts are reached, the retryContext should be updated to exhausted=true, but I still see it false as seen in the log below in my recovery method:

{"@timestamp":"2022-08-17T13:22:11.805+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Rolled back with retryContext-[RetryContext: count=2, lastException=com.graph.Neo4jException, exhausted=false]"}

Since, the maxAttempts have been reached and the recoverymethod is triggered, should not exhaused=true?

Note: maxAttempts is set to 2.
Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of `exhausted`.

`exhausted` is a flag available to the user to terminate the retries early (for some reason) by calling `setExhaustedOnly()` on the context.

The context has no knowledge about the max attempts so can't coerce the exhausted flag to true in its `toString()` (and shouldn't anyway because of its special meaning).